# How do I update my GCP vm to the latest version?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, apt

I've been running a prototype VM for a year now. I haven't updated it in months. I tried to update it recently using `sudo apt update`.

However I get the following error:

```
    Ign:1 http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Ign:2 http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Err:4 http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 35.196.128.168 80]
Err:5 http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 35.196.128.168 80]
Err:6 http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 35.196.128.168 80]
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

My vm is a Google Compute Engine instance.

Comment: Make a backup from your data and try to upgrade to a supported release. Try using the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) and let me know whether this helped you to resolve the issue.

Comment: http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu doesn't work for "old unsupported". ....  20.10 groovy was moved to old releases http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu distribution you are using seems to be outdated, and when this happens Ubuntu changes the servers of the repositories.
To be able to update your distribution, edit /etc/apt/sources.list and change **archive.ubuntu.com** and **security.ubuntu.com**, to **old-releases.ubuntu.com**.

But as mentioned by @ Knud Larsen,  20.10 groovy was moved to old releases [old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/), and [us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) doesn't work for "old unsupported". Hence, you will not be able to change us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu to old-releases.ubuntu.com. You can try [moving the VM to another zone/region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually) and try to update the version.

**Steps to upgrade ubuntu version:**

1. Create a backup of your server or vm.
2. Upgrade all installed packages of Ubuntu version by running **sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade** command.
3. Reboot the Ubuntu Linux system by tying the **sudo reboot command**.
4. Install the Ubuntu update tool, run: **sudo apt install update-manager-core**.
5. Start the upgrade procedure, run: **sudo do-release-upgrade**.
6. Reboot the box, run: **sudo reboot**.
7. Verify upgrades.

Comment: Why can't I use old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu? Does google do something special with their repositories?

Comment: As mentioned,  old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu is only not supported by us-east4.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.